# Как изменить параметр шейдера у материала через код С#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Shader с двумя публичными параметрами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный Shader висит на материале:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно через код C# изменить параметр Speed у материала, на котором висит данный Shader? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ok google: [unity3d shader set property](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity3d+shader+set+property&rlz=1C1CHZN_ruRU993RU993&oq=unity3d+shader+se&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30i625j0i22i30j0i22i30i625j0i15i22i30j69i64.6513j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Yaroslav, Спасибо Большое!